# C / Cython: Initial content of an malloc memory allocation

Tags: c, initialization, malloc, cython

Code:

```
cpdef values(int n):
    cdef size_t i
    cdef double * v = <double *> malloc(sizeof(double) * n)
    if v is NULL:
        abort()
    for i in range(n):
        print v[i]
```

Output:

```
>>> values(5)
1.06816855917e-306
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
```

Question:
**Why does this function print zeros and where does the leading number come from / what does it mean?** I thought unlike `calloc`, `malloc` does not initialize to zero, as said on wikipedia and [in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/604104/does-c-allocate-memory-automatically-for-me). What is happening here behind the scenes of Python / Cython / C?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For all intents and purposes the contents of `malloc`'ed memory block is to be treated as random and undetermined. The values found in the allocated buffer may be contents of memory blocks previously freed.

Answer (score 0):

The memory allocated by `malloc()` by default contains garbage values.`malloc()` does not initialize memory to zero. 0(zero) can be one of the garbage value.