# Cython: safe way to check whether element in malloc memoryview is assigned

Tags: c++, c, malloc, cython, memoryview

I want to create various small memoryviews in function temporarily and release them when the function is finished. Seems initialize the memoryview by `malloc` is better, based on the comparisons performed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21054369/3003072), and actually is faster. As only part of the elements in each of these small memoryviews are assinged, what's the safe way to check whether it is assigned?

Here is the code and comparisons using `malloc` and numpy's `ndarray`:

```
## test_malloc.pyx

cimport cython
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np

from libc.stdlib cimport malloc, free

np.import_array()


@cython.wraparound(False)
@cython.boundscheck(False)
cdef int _num_assign_malloc():
    cdef:
        Py_ssize_t n = 50
        double *x = <double *> malloc(n * sizeof(double))
        Py_ssize_t i
        int k = 0

    x[5] = 1.
    x[8] = 1.
    x[38] = 1.

    for i in range(n):
        if x[i] == 1.:
            k += 1

    free(x)
    return k


@cython.wraparound(False)
@cython.boundscheck(False)
cdef int _num_assign_ndarray():
    cdef:
        Py_ssize_t n = 50
        double[::1] x = np.zeros(n, dtype=np.float64)
        Py_ssize_t i
        int k = 0

    x[5] = 1.
    x[8] = 1.
    x[38] = 1.

    for i in range(n):
        if x[i] == 1.:
            k += 1

    return k


cpdef test_num_malloc():
    return _num_assign_malloc()


cpdef test_num_ndarray():
    return _num_assign_ndarray()
```

`timeit`:

```
>>> import timeit
>>> t = timeit.Timer("from test_malloc import test_num_malloc; test_num_malloc()")
>>> t.timeit(10000)
# 0.0111
>>> t = timeit.Timer("from test_malloc import test_num_ndarray; test_num_ndarray()")
>>> t.timeit(10000)
# 0.0246
```

When I check what are those unassigned elements in `malloc`ed memoryview:

```
@cython.wraparound(False)
@cython.boundscheck(False)
cdef _malloc_unassign():
    cdef:
        Py_ssize_t n = 20
        double *x = <double *> malloc(n * sizeof(double))
        double[::1] y = np.zeros(n, dtype=np.float64)
        Py_ssize_t i

    x[5] = 1.
    x[8] = 1.

    for i in range(n):
        y[i] = x[i]

    free(x)
    return y


cpdef test_malloc():
    return _malloc_unassign()
```

I got:

```
>>> from test_malloc import test_malloc
>>> for t in test_malloc():
...    print(t)
...
    6.230420704259778e-307
    3.5604305343967845e-307
    1.6021930623879718e-306
    2.447635570273665e-307
    1.6911933005114767e-306
    1.0
    1.0570034520433751e-307
    1.2461038328174693e-306
    1.0
    8.066321387750432e-308
    1.201607109425611e-306
    1.691193300407861e-306
    1.2906222865963489e-306
    1.4241722150642528e-306
    1.3351264799003858e-306
    7.56596412080425e-307
    7.565984490202416e-307
    1.6021903463576915e-306
    1.424109743093715e-306
    2.2250738585072396e-306
```

Seems I can simply cheched whether it is assigned by `x[i] == 1.`, but I don't think this is good enough, especially according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21018687/3003072), those unassigned elements are treated as random; and if I used `int` instead of `double`.

**Edit**

---

Thanks @DavidW for providing `calloc`.
Adding this to my `test_malloc.pyx`:

```
@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)
cdef int _num_assign_calloc():
    cdef:
        Py_ssize_t n = 50
        double *x = <double *> calloc(n, sizeof(double))
        Py_ssize_t i
        int k = 0

    x[5] = 1.
    x[8] = 1.
    x[38] = 1.

    for i in range(n):
        if x[i] == 1.:
            k += 1

    free(x)
    return k
```

`timeit`:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> time_malloc = []
>>> for i in range(1000):
...     t = timeit.Timer("from core.test_malloc import test_num_malloc; test_num_malloc()")
...     time_malloc.append(t.timeit(10000))
...
...
>>> time_ndarr = []
>>> for i in range(1000):
...     t = timeit.Timer("from core.test_malloc import test_num_ndarray; test_num_ndarray()")
...     time_ndarr.append(t.timeit(10000))
...
...
>>> time_calloc = []
>>> for i in range(1000):
...     t = timeit.Timer("from core.test_malloc import test_num_calloc; test_num_calloc()")
...     time_calloc.append(t.timeit(10000))
...
...
>>> print("mean: %.4f, std: %.4f" % (np.mean(time_malloc), np.std(time_malloc)))
mean: 0.0098, std: 0.0034
>>> print("mean: %.4f, std: %.4f" % (np.mean(time_calloc), np.std(time_calloc)))
mean: 0.0098, std: 0.0026
>>> print("mean: %.4f, std: %.4f" % (np.mean(time_ndarr), np.std(time_ndarr)))
mean: 0.0177, std: 0.0033
```

Comment: Why would you need to check that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You cannot reliably work out if an element a malloced array has been assigned. That would require the C compiler to add a whole bunch of extra code and storage to track what has been written to.

Try `calloc`, which does produce a zeroed array.

It's worth emphasising that one of the reasons `malloc` is fast is because it skips the initialization so you may be after an impossible "best of both worlds" - all the advantages of initialization without any of the time cost. With that said, I'd expect `calloc` to beat Numpy.

Comment: Thanks. `malloc` and `calloc` are comparable. I have edited my question by adding `calloc` for comparion.